# Plot normal distribution into a histogram with 1000 samples between 1 to 10 interval

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, math, data-science

For each of the following distributions, plot its pdf in the given interval and a histogram based  on  1000  samples.  Use `pdf(x, *args)`to  compute  the  probability  densities  for the given array of x values, e.g.,norm.pdf(x, a, b). Use `rvs(*args, n)`to sample n values, e.g. `norm.rvs(a, b, n)`.

(a)  Normal distribution: `N(5,1.5)`. Plot interval: `[0,10]`

my current solution:

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.stats import beta, expon, gamma, laplace, norm  

x = norm.rvs(5,1.5,1000)
graph = plt.plot(x,norm.pdf(x,5,1.5))
```

Comment: Heyoka, you can help others help you by saying what is the problem that you have encountered. My advice is to add some text to your problem statement to say what is the error or other problem you have run into.

Comment: there is no error but dont sure if i did what is written in the task?